# Conditionally delete an element from an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'd like to conditionally delete an element from an array of arbitrary length, e.g.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
condition = 3

for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] >= condition:
        list.pop(i)
```

Would result in

```
list = [1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Is there a more 'pythonic' way of doing this, such as list comprehension?

Thandel

Comment: Your code is buggy. If you start with a list `[1, 4, 5, 1, 1]` your result would be `[1, 5, 1, 1]` (after you catch the `IndexError`).  The most pythonic thing would be to write working code.  (If you delete the item at index 2 the item at index 3 slides over to replace it. If the next index you check is index 3 you've just skipped an item. The `IndexError` is because you calculate indexes on the original size. If you delete items you will have indexes that point past the end.)

Comment: Using `list` as a name of a variable is considered bad form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the original list to be modified, you would need something like what you are doing. if you want a new list the following one liner works

```
[i for i in llist if i < 3]
```

Please note that I have renamed your variable as llist since `list` is a built in.

Comment: `llist[:] = [i for i in llist if i < 3]` would be a way to do this while mutating the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, using list comprehension:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
condition = 3
newlist = [x for x in list if x < condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to stick to the `list` datatype? Have you thought of using numpy arrays?
A pythonic way with numpy would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])
condition = 3

conditioned_arr = arr[arr < condition]

>>> print(conditioned_arr)
array([1, 2, 2, 1])
```